# Generic Type Comparison, Assignment, And Return Based On Custom Attribute

Tags: c#

Don’t know why I can’t figure this out…

I am using a comparison method that takes two types, loops through them, and using reflection builds a report of differences of the fields. This is more or less a detailed comparison of the two types. The types have the same properties. While I am doing the comparison, each of the fields also has a custom attribute associated with it. In the below, the **Difference** object stores the names, and other properties related to the comparison operation.

To do the comparison, I use the following:

```
public static List<Difference<T>> Detailed Difference <T>(this T val1, T val2)
{
    List< Difference <T>> differences = new List< Difference <T>>();
    FieldInfo[] fi = val1.GetType().GetFields();
    foreach (FieldInfo f in fi)
    {
        Difference <T> v = new Difference <T>();
        v.Prop = f.Name;
        v.ValA = f.GetValue(val1);
        v.ValB = f.GetValue(val2);
        v.ObjectA = val1;
        v.ObjectB = val2;
        v.MyCustomAttribute = (MyCustomAttribute Attribute) Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(f, typeof (MyCustomAttribute Attribute));
        differences.Add(v)
    }
    return differences;
}
```

MyCustomAttribute is an enum that contains FooA and FooB.

If **MyCustomAttribute** equals **FooA**, the value of **ValA** should be used to build a return of type **T** to add to the method **List** return. If **MyCustomAttribute** equals **FooB**, the value of **ValB** should be used when building the new type. The problem I am having is the generic doesn’t allow me to instantiate a new type of **T**, for pretty obvious reasons...so I can’t figure out how to, more or less, map the property values based on reading the custom attribute.

Comment: You can make a new instance of `T` if you specify that `T` has a parameterless default constructor.  You may not be able to specify that.  Further, any time someone is trying to examine the actual types used in a generic method, I have to question - is this solution actually **generic**?  If it is, the type shouldn't matter.

Comment: Also, `val1` and `val2` will always be the same type. The types may differ between invocations of the method, but they must match. If you want to allow different types you'd need to call one `T1` and the other `T2` (for instance) and then make sure both are specified in the signature.

Comment: "if you specify that T has a parameterless default constructor" can you elaborate? How would the properties be assigned?

Comment: Yes, to do so you'd constrain the method by saying `where T : new()`.  But in doing so you can only use types that **do in fact** have a parameterless default constructor.

Comment: Actually, they don't necessarily have to be the same type. The code is legally called with `Difference<object>("test", 10)`

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Haha, clever. I actually chuckled when I read that. Be honest though, I think that really goes against the spirit of how a generic type / method is supposed to work. What do you gain by casting each all the way back down to its base class? You couldn't do anything interesting with it in the method body since they'd be treated as `object` both.

Comment: Ok, I get the default constructor and my types needing. However, instantiating a new T object, how does one map the properties to the new type based on the custom attribute read?

Comment: Well, considering that they don't necessarily have to be the same type, I question the purpose of a method named "**Detailed** Difference" *[sic]*. I'd think that the actual properties/fields of the underlying objects, and not of the base type, would be of interest instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you include the `new` [constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx), then `new T()` will be possible. Then you can use [`FieldInfo.SetValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6z33zd7h%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to set the values in it.

```
public static List<Difference<T>> Detailed Difference<T>(this T val1, T val2)
    where T : new()
{
    T newValue = new T();
    // later...
    v.MyCustomAttribute = // whatever it is
    if (v.MyCustomAttribute == MyCustomAttribute.FooA)
        f.SetValue(newValue, v.ValA);
    else if (v.MyCustomAttribute == MyCustomAttribute.FooB)
        f.SetValue(newValue, v.ValB);
    differences.Add(v);
    // other stuff...
}
```

If this won't work with your types, you'll need something passed in to your method. Since you apparently only need one new object, and always one object, you could just take another `T`:

```
public static List<Difference<T>> Detailed Difference<T>(this T val1, T val2,
                                                         T newValue)
{

// call like
var diff = myClass1.Difference(myClass2, new MyClass(someParam));
```

For more advanced scenarios, take a `Func<T>`, so that you can call it whenever needed:

```
public static List<Difference<T>> Detailed Difference<T>(this T val1, T val2,
                                                         Func<T> getNewValue)
{
    T newValue = getNewValue();

// call like
var diff = myClass1.Difference(myClass2, () => new MyClass(someParam));
```